# create and save pdf document into external storage in android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am trying to create a pdf file and save it to sd card. I searched for solutions to my problem but what i found in the net was about creating and saving a file or image. But neither solves my problem. Here's my sample code:

```
 public void createPdf(){
     Document document = new Document();  
     try {           
             PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("DIRECTORY_PDF") + java.io.File.separator + "droidtext" + java.io.File.separator + "HelloWorld"));
             document.open();
             document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
     } catch (DocumentException de) {
             System.err.println(de.getMessage());
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
             System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
     }
     document.close();
```

and here's what the logcat says:

`02-21 06:28:08.001: W/System.err(859): /mnt/sdcard/DIRECTORY_PDF/droidtext/HelloWorld: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: have you created DIRECTORY_PDF/droidtext on sd card

Comment: isnt it created in that line of code? I was using  getExternalStorageDirectory() before. then i read that if im using API level 8 or higher(which i am) i should use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory doesn't create the directory. When you use PDFWriter please make sure that the output directory exists